# GingerBread APP not being deployed on ICS

Tags: android

I have deployed an app using 2.3.3 SDK. When I am trying to debug it on ICS 4.0.4 eclipse is not permitting me to install the app and I am unable to take screen shots either. 
Kindly let me know the solution for the same.

Comment: You should really try to put some more effort into your questions. Reading the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is a good start. In this case the error messaged would have been nice to have. Also some information on what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restarted by eclipse and phone. It worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Make minSdkVersion: 10 and targetSdkVersion:15

Try something like this in Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Also if you are using any Google features like GoogleMaps, you need to use the Google API and not the normal Android (in eclipse)

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
has already been added. Also I am unable to take screen shots either